# Express route not being recognized. Responds with 'Cannot GET'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var db = require('./db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.listen(80);

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', "./views");

// app.get('/', _GetMainPage);
// app.get('/sites', _GetSites);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Support encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Support json encoded bodies
app.use(require('./controllers'));
```

**./controllers/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/', require('./sites'));
router.use('/site', require('./site'));

module.exports = router;
```

**./controllers/sites.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var site = require('../models/site');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    site.getAll(function(err, rows){
        if(err) {
           res.send(err);
           return;
        }

        res.render('sites', { sites : rows });
    });
});
```

**./controllers/site.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router =  express.Router();
var site = require('../models/site');

router.get('/site', function(req, res) {
    // console.log("get /site received. req.body: " + req.body);
    res.render('site', {
            site: {
                name : req.params.name
            }
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I request **localhost/site** I get a response saying:

> Cannot GET /site

**localhost/** works perfectly

I have been looking at this for a while and can't find the problem yet. If there is anything I can add, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to /site/site? Your site.js route is relative to the route you provided in use. So it should be `router.get('/' ...` not `router.get('/site' ...`

Comment: That's exactly what the problem is, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to the person that  commented with the answer:

> What happens if you navigate to /site/site? Your site.js route is relative to the route you provided in use. So it should be router.get('/' ... not router.get('/site' ...

The **./controllers/site** route is already being routed to **/site**. On top of this I was calling `router.get('/site', ...)`. This means it was actually routing to **/site/site**.

The solution is to just use `router.get('/', ...)` in the **site.js** file instead.

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me, thank you.

Basically, the root path in the sub-app is defined in your core app where you mount it via the `app.use()` method.

the best example I can find from **app.mountpath** docs is here:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router

> The app.mountpath property contains one or more path patterns on which a sub-app was mounted.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express(); // the main app
var admin = express(); // the sub app

admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(admin.mountpath); // /admin
  res.send('Admin Homepage');
});

app.use('/admin', admin); // mount the sub app
```

> It is similar to the baseUrl property of the req object, except
>   req.baseUrl returns the matched URL path, instead of the matched
>   patterns.
>
> If a sub-app is mounted on multiple path patterns, app.mountpath
>   returns the list of patterns it is mounted on, as shown in the
>   following example.

```
var admin = express();

admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(admin.mountpath); // [ '/adm*n', '/manager' ]
  res.send('Admin Homepage');
});

var secret = express();
secret.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(secret.mountpath); // /secr*t
  res.send('Admin Secret');
});

admin.use('/secr*t', secret); // load the 'secret' router on '/secr*t', on the 'admin' sub app
app.use(['/adm*n', '/manager'], admin); // load the 'admin' router on '/adm*n' and '/manager', on the parent app
```